# Play2 Scala models - merge objects

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I'm using Play2+Scala+ReactiveMongo to build a web application. Since `mongodb` doesn't require all documents to have the same structure, I make a large use of case classes with `Options` as parameters to implement models. For example:

```
case class PersonInfo(address: Option[String],
                      telephone: Option[String],
                      age: Option[Int],
                      job: Option[String])
case class Person(id: UUID, name: String, info: PersonInfo)
```

Now suppose I want to merge two `PersonInfo` objects, for example in a update function. I do right now is:

```
val updPInfo = old.copy(address = new.address orElse address,
                        telephone = new.telephone orElse telephone,
                        age = new.age orElse age,
                        job = new.job orElse job)
```

This way I have an object that has new values where they were specified by the `new` object and old values for the remaining ones.

This actually works fine, but it is bit ugly to see when the list of parameters grows.

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the only place you need this is in mongo, you can do it, like this:

```
collection.
      update(
          Json.obj("_id" -> id),
          Json.obj("$set" -> Json.toJson(new))
      )
```

That way you'll have correct presentation in DB, which you can read and use afterwards.

*or*

If you need it in Scala, you can merge 2 Json presentations:

```
val merged = Json.toJson(old).deepMerge(new).as[PersonInfo]
```

Which is not quite better, then what you are doing now.